# Broadcast Receiver when Location/GPS is called

Tags: android, gps, location, broadcast

Is there any Broadcast, Intent-Filter for location, network, gps, Google? I mean like a Firewall. I want to intercept any app which tries to localize your cellphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the passive location provider to get informed every time an app receives a location update.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER

This, however, will not let you intercept location updates in a way that "consumes" them.

Answer (score 1):

Android is designed such that each app is in it's own world and doesn't know anything about other apps. So no.

You could only know when the internet, location services, etc, is available.

So you could know when your location has changed and catch that update, but you have no way of knowing if some other app is using that data.